# How do I install Ubuntu on an external harddrive?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, macbook

I have a 320 GB external hard drive connected to my MacBook Pro (5, 5). There are 2 partitions on it, one has data and the other one is empty. I tried installing Ubuntu on the empty partition but it gives me an error about my partition map. Does anybody know the solution to this?

Comment: Please add (at least) what error you got precisely

Answer (score 0):

Use caution if attempting the following! Be sure you know what you are doing.

I believe you have to temporarily modify your bios settings to have the primary disabled, and have the connected external be recognized (the specific settings will differ between machine varieties).  With this accomplished you can then boot from live cd or usb and should be able to install as you normally would except it will be on the primary.  After that is completed return to bios after rebooting again, re-enable the primary drive and set your boot order preference.

That said, if you are not extremely comfortable messing with these settings do not proceed as you may be very sad at the outcome.

One other option, that I'm not sure if it will work or not is to create another smaller partition within the free partition and try to use unetbootin to image that partition only,  I have not tried to image a partition with it before, but if you can select this smaller partition within the unetbootin program I think you will get the result you are looking for, then you should be able to mount the main segment of the partition when booting from it, but as I said I haven't tried this, only in theory...I was planning on trying a similar setup as you are in the near future and if I get that done before you give it a go I will update the info as needed.